# How to pass the value of a variable instead of a reference into a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

If I use the code below, the alert will say `10`. I want it to say `5`.

```
var a = 5;
var b = document.getElementById("element").onclick = ()=>alert(a);
a = 10;
```

How can I create an event listener that uses the **value** of a variable from the time it was created, rather than a **reference** that will change if I modify value later?

Comment: Reassign it to another variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an IIFE that captures the current value of `a`.

```js
var a = 5;
document.getElementById("element").onclick = ((x) => ()=>alert(x))(a);
a = 10;
```

```html
<button id="element">Click</button>
```